# Is there a volume mixer?

Tags: sound, 12.04, volume-control

I was using Windows 7 and decided to replace it with Ubuntu 12.04, but I couldn't find any program with similar functionality to **Volume Mixer** in windows 7:

[image: volume mixer in windows 7]

if there is any program or a way you know to do so, I would really appreciate knowing about it.

Comment: I don't know about 12.04. But 11.10 and all versions I've ever seen come with one preinstalled and enabled by default. Perhaps your soundcard is not working?

Comment: Sound preferences.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is Sound Settings which will allow you to change all sound options much like Windows.

[image: Sound Selection]

You can adjust the slider to change volume,mute the output, control media playback etc. 
Once you choose sound Settings you can adjust all preferences by selecting a tab.

[image: All settings]

---

If you want to have the functionality of the Windows sound menu control you will need to install Alsamixer from the software centre which as it's description says;

**GNOME Alsa Mixer**

A 'volume control' application. You can use it to adjust the volume of different sound sources of your sound card.
It has a nice graphical user interface and a lot of features:

- Access to all of your computers sound card and audio sources
- Possibility to give them custom names
- Only display the mixer controls you need
- Access to all the extra features some sound cards offer, like 3D enhancement, microphone gain, boost etc.
- And more....

The application uses the ALSA sound API which is installed by default.

[image: ALSA Mixer]

Comment: sorry my bad i meant this one:
http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/image69.png
it s used to adjust the volume of one application only, or all applications at once.

Comment: I think `pavucontrol` is the pulseaudio equivalent of `alsamixer`...

Comment: @fossfreedom Yes it is. `pavucontrol` is a more bit complex than the regular Configuration screen of sounds. The youtube audio is under plugin container, as example. Thank you.

Comment: @fossfreedom you   know what is sad? when I open xfce settings and search for `audio`  or `sound`, `pavucontrol` doesn't pop up although it's pre-installed. anyway, thank you, this should actually have its own question

Answer (score 8):

Go to Applications tab in Sound settings.

[image: sound settings]

Answer (score 1):

You can get to a mixer through your terminal actually. Open your terminal, and type in `sudo alsamixer` it will then ask you for a password, put in your password and a GUI should appear. It explains itself from there

Comment: Why `sudo`? The default user account comes with audio management privileges and any other user account created without them likely doesn't have `sudo` privileges.

Comment: thanks for an answer -- no volume mixer on ubuntu was wrecking my head -- i'm confident I can manage with using sudo. It's likely necessary because of the low level nature of sound drivers. A non issue to anyone with common sense... (i'll just do a quice google and see if the community has anything bad to say about alsmixer)  I do hope you don't stop adding useful and helpful answers because of ... well you know.. ;)

Comment: But this ALSA MIXER is not configurable by application or is it ?

and the SOUND SETTINGS explained by you were pidgin is only available when the message is BEING SENT ..well is not very useful and of course is not UBUNTU's fault but a integration issue between UBUNTU and PIDGIN..i guess