# Headphones not working in UBUNTU 12.10. I have DELL 5520 laptop. Speakers are working fine.

Tags: sound, headphones

When I plug in headphones, I hear only the music in the song and the lyrics is played in an inaudible low volume. And there is a lot of noise also.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a mixer issue (if not hardware/driver)

Check out this post:
[Is there a volume mixer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119574/is-there-a-volume-mixer)