# Ubuntu 14.04 Headphone and PC speakers are working together

Tags: headphones, speakers

I try to hear with my Headphones while they're plugged in 
and when they're plugged out I would like to hear with my pc speakers 
but now while the headphones are plugged in I can hear both. 
How do I fix it?

I am using an old HP laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the exact same problem on my netbook when I was on the train.

I as organising some party music, and was jumping through the music with my headphones in. Then someone asks me to turn down my music, and I look rather bemused at them, not realising that I was sharing my music with the rest of the train!

The only solution I found was to use the advanced mixer whereby I could adjust the volume of the headphones and external speakers independantly.

In the end I used the hotkey on my netbook to switch between headphones or speakers, rather than using it as a mute function.

I've updated my system since, clean install,  and haven't had the same problem, but I woildnt be surprised if it would have been possible to get the change to be automatic using dmesg alerts somehow.

David

Edit :

The 'advanced mixer' is an option in the sound / volume system that comes as standard in ubunut - I've never had to download anything special. See this ask question.
[Is there a volume mixer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119574/is-there-a-volume-mixer)

Dmesg : this is part of the system log in Linux system. When an event occurs a message is often sent to dmesg and also any appropriate other log in the system. See this page on the official help.Ubuntu pages.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles.

Hope that helps for you.

Comment: Thanks , What is "advanced mixer whereby" ? and what is "dmesg alerts "?

Comment: @user63898 in St found another question here on ask http://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in?rq=1 that suggests it may have been a bug, this may also solve your problem.